# Phasor transformation to sinus or cosinus?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, conventions, complex-numbers

In my EM waves lecture, our lecturer somehow explained the way we make phasor transformation of a particular function such as $$A\cos(\omega t-( \alpha +\beta z))u_{y}$$ converted into phasor form of $$H_{S}=Ae^{-j( \alpha +\beta z)}u_{y}$$ but sometimes we reconvert it into sinus function in some problems  and I didn't quite understand when to do when. From Euler's equation I assume we take the imaginary part for sinus and real part for cosine but in phasor form everything looks like imaginary therefore how am I suppose to know which function to use?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how everything "looks imaginary"?

Comment: "sometimes we reconvert it into sinus function in some problems" -- can you provide an explicit example where this is done? (ideally from the same source as your existing example.)

Comment: The question is not very clear about the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From elementary trigonometry we have: $\sin(\theta-\delta)=\cos(\theta)$. In EM we understand $\delta$ like the time gap between two waves. When you apply initial conditions to your problem (for ex. $E(t=0)=0$) you can calculate $\delta$, you can use both expressions (sine or cosine) if you be careful defining $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks! After solving a couple of problems I noticed that too, we are deciding according to the initial conditions given such as t=0 and the phase difference etc. I didn't realise that before, I thought it was random which didn't make sense but now I understood.